# How to find tuples that overlap a given range tuple

Tags: python, list, search, tuples, overlap

Say I have a list full of tuples denoting a "from" and a "to" time:

```
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
```

And I want to be able to retrieve a list of tuple that overlap with a given tuple:

```
searchTuple = (3,11)
result = findOverlap(tuples, searchTuple)
```

This code should return the following list:

```
[ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15) ]
```

While a searchTuple of (16, 22) should only return the last tuple (15,20)

What is the most efficient way to code this retrieval? I tried various things but I am having trouble getting the algorithm to work properly. I figured the following different "overlaps" that I am interested in catching:

```
a) tuple_min < find_min AND tuple_max > find_max

search tuple -> |         | 
            |----------------| the search tuple is entirely contained

b) tuple_min > find_min AND tuple_max > find_max

         |         |
            |----------------| the left part of the tuple overlaps

c) tuple_min < find_min AND tuple_max < find_max

              |         |
    |----------------| the right part of the tuple overlaps
```

However, the results I got after implementing this ended up giving me wrong results... Where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: you have to post your code here, and i think someone was asking about your assigment before here, so try to google a bit :)

Comment: is tuples given in a sorted fashion based on the first element of each period?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question because I found an elegant solution:

```
tuples = [(0,5), (5,10), (10,15), (15,20)]

def overlap(tuples, search):
    res = []
    for t in tuples:
        if(t[1]>search[0] and t[0]<search[1]):
            res.append(t)
    return res

search = (1,11)
print overlap(tuples, search)
```

returns as expected:

```
[(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't covered the case where the search tuple entirely encloses the current tuple with which it is compared to. In your case, say (3,11) against (5,10)

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty list comprehension:

```
>>> t = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
>>> o = (3,11)
>>> [(i[0],i[1]) for i in t if i[0] >= o[0] and i[0] <= o[1] or i[1] >= o[0] and i[1] <= o[1]]
#returns: 
[(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15)]
>>> o = (16,22)
#returns
[(15, 20)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the dumbest code you can write:

```
def findOverlap(tuples, searchTuple):
    result = []
    for p in tuples:
        if  (p[0] <= searchTuple[0] and searchTuple[0] <p[1]) or \
            (p[0] < searchTuple[1] and p[1] >searchTuple[1]) or \
            (p[0] < searchTuple[0] and p[1] searchTuple[1]):
            result.append(p)
        if (p[0] > searchTuple[1]):
            break
```

I hope I have not mistaken the indexes!
if you sort tuples you can improve code performance by doing a smarter search.
I came across similar problem years ago when I was trying to learn algorithms. so I guess it is a popular type of question and you can find efficient codes by googling

Answer (score 1):

This method is beginner friendly and should do the trick

```
def findOverlap(tuples, searchTuple):
  result=[]
  for tuple in tuples:
    if searchTuple[0] in range(tuple[0],tuple[1]): #search for the first value
      result.append(tuple)
      continue
    if len(result)>0 and searchTuple[1] in range(tuple[0],tuple[1]): #search for the last value
      result.append(tuple)
      break
    if len(result)>0:
      result.append(tuple) #add all elements between first and last
  return result
```

`range(tuple[0],tuple[1])` just returns all the numbers from one to the other, so if its looking through the `(5,10)` tuple it will return `[5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Then `searchTuple[0] in range(tuple[0],tuple[1])` checks to see if the first element in searchTuple is within that range.

`result.append(tuple)` adds that tuple to the list of things to return from the method.

The rest of it is loop manipulation and formatting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (3,11)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
```

================================================================================

Here are some sample output for various values of 'searchTuple':

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 2 ranges, and bounds don't coincide
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (8,11)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> [(5, 10), (10, 15)]
```

&

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 3 ranges, and bounds don't coincide. Also, lower bounds is 'out-of-bound' and negative
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (-3,11)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> [(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15)]
```

&

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 2 ranges, lower bound coincides.
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (5,11)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> [(5, 10), (10, 15)]
```

&

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 1 ranges, both bounds coincide.
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (5,10)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> [(5, 10)]
```

&

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 2 ranges, and upper bound coincides.
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (3,10)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> [(0, 5), (5, 10)]
```

&

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 2 ranges, and lower bound coincides. Also, upper bounds is 'out-of-bound'.
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (10,49)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> [(10, 15), (15, 20)]
```

&

```
# In this case, 'searchTuple' is overlaping 0 ranges has both bounds are 'out-of-bound'.
tuples = [ (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15,20) ]
searchTuple = (25,49)
result = [tInnerRange for tInnerRange in tuples if searchTuple[0] >= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[0] < tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[1] > tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] <= tInnerRange[1] or searchTuple[0] <= tInnerRange[0] and searchTuple[1] >= tInnerRange[1]]
print(result)

====> []
```